# Difference in two tables display difference in rows in single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables which return 3 columns (Account #, Amount, Site Number)

Sample:
Table # 1

```
111111, 200, 14
111111,-200, 14
111111, 400, 15
111111, -400, 15
```

Table # 2

```
111111, 201, 14
111111,-200, 14
111111, 400, 15
111111, -400, 15
```

I am trying to graft a query that will no only show me the differences between the two tables like minus or where not exists but allow me pivot the data that is different from the one table to a column in the return

Something like this:

```
Act#:   TblA Amount TblB Amount Site
111111, 200,        201,        14
```

When I use minus it simply gives me back the row in the top table that is different so if I did:

```
select * from TblA
MINUS
select * from TblB
```

Result:

```
111111, 200, 14
```

I know there must be way to do this and any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following queries will help.  Principle: find the differences between the tables (contents of A minus contents of B, and vice versa),
then use these in a join, in order to "collapse" the result set.  Using your test data (Oracle 12c):

```
(
  select c1, c2, c3, 'in table#1' location from table#1
  minus
  select c1, c2, c3, 'in table#1'  from table#2
)
union all
(
  select c1, c2, c3, 'in table#2 (not in table#1)' from table#2
  minus
  select c1, c2, c3, 'in table#2 (not in table#1)' from table#1
);

-- result
        C1         C2         C3 LOCATION                     
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------------
    111111        200         14 in table#1                 
    111111        201         14 in table#2 (not in table#1)
```

If there are no duplicates for the C1/C3 combinations, the following JOIN will give you the required result.  (Maybe this will be "good enough" for your situation ...)

```
select 
  A.c1
--, B.c1
, A.c2
, B.c2
, A.c3
--, B.c3
from
(
  select * from table#1
  minus
  select * from table#2
) A join (
  select * from table#2
  minus
  select * from table#1
) B on A.c1 = B.c1 and A.c3 = B.c3 
;

-- result
        C1         C2         C2         C3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    111111        200        201         14
```

[Dbfiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=56c100bed747456328119655f75a47aa)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabA a
FULL JOIN tabB b
  ON a.id = b.id  -- here should be PK or UNIQUE col
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.Account, a.Amount, a.Site_Number FROM dual
                  INTERSECT
                  SELECT b.Account, b.Amount, b.Site_Number FROM dual);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=788bae88cc1363e3ec76b565a45400cf)**

Comment: Would this solution still work if the table does not have a primary key or any unique key

Comment: @Josh No. This approach assumes that there is PK.

Comment: I guess that is out then. Is there anything that can be done besides simply displaying both records if no primary key exists?